# Are there any differences between bullseye and stable?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, source, distributions

I was looking at directories in https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/. By comparing timestamps I could easily tell that `bullseye` and `stable` are the same thing. So is there no difference in behavior even if I change my `/etc/apt/sources.list` entry from `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/ bullseye main contrib non-free` to `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/ stable main contrib non-free`?

Answer (score 5):

Stable and bullseye *currently* (at time of writing) refer to the same version. Debian uses Toy Story character names as permanent release names (with the exclusion of *sid* which is always the unstable release), whereas releases are also given relative release names e.g. *stable*, *testing* and *unstable*.
See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ftparchives for more information on these release names.

At time of writing, *stable* refers to Debian 11, which is also codenamed *bullseye*, but this will change sometime in the future.

> So is there no difference in behavior even if I change my `/etc/apt/sources.list` entry from `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/ bullseye main contrib non-free` to `deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/ stable main contrib non-free`?

While the two codenames refer to the same release, there's no difference, however in the future when releases roll-over and *bookworm* (currently *testing*) becomes the new *stable*, then the former line will stay with `bullseye` (becoming the new `oldstable`) and the latter line will upgrade to `bookworm` (becoming the new `stable`).